# Why does predicate not return a Boolean?

Tags: scala, predicate

I'm trying to complete a very simple exercise - filter function:

```
def filter[A](x: List[A], f: A => Boolean): List[A] = {
 for(item <- x){
  if(f(item))
   yield item
  }
 }
```

But it does not compile, seems that f(item) returns something different from Boolean, but I can't understand, why. To check it, I tried to do so:

```
 var b = Boolean
 b = f(item)
```

After that I got an error "expression of type Boolean doesn't conform to expected type Boolean.type". But I don't understand this explanation.

Could you please help to understand what's wrong here? The function is called so:

```
 val list = 1 :: 2 :: 3 :: 4:: 5 :: 6 :: Nil
 val list2 = filter[Int](list, _ % 2 == 0)
```

Comment: `x.flatMap(item => if (f(item)) Some(item) else None)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Per the [language specification](https://www.scala-lang.org/files/archive/spec/2.11/06-expressions.html#for-comprehensions-and-for-loops), a for-comprehension's `yield` clause cannot be inside a compound expression, e.g. inside a pair of braces. It must be the *outermost* word of the for-comprehension's return expression.

As Tim explains, your `if` must also be in a particular place to act as a filter. In that position it's called a *guard clause* (refer to the spec to see the exact syntax).

Answer (score 2):

The predicate does return `Boolean` but the syntax of your `for` loop is wrong. It should be like this:

```
def filter[A](x: List[A], f: A => Boolean): List[A] =
  for (item <- x if f(item)) yield item
```

But this is even better:

```
def filter[A](x: List[A], f: A => Boolean): List[A] =
  x.filter(f)
```

Answer (score 2):

You probably know that you could simply use the `filter` method of List directly:

```
def filter[A](x: List[A], f: A => Boolean): List[A] = x.filter(f)
```

But if you want to implement your `filter` method using a for-comprehension you could do it as follows

```
def filter[A](x: List[A], f: A => Boolean): List[A] = {
  for {
    item <- x
    if (f(item))
  } yield item
}
```